# login block without a "log in" button

Tags: blocks, users

I want to create a very minimal login block and thus wouldn't like to have the "log in" button at all. I would like to have only the username and password fields, and log on by hitting "enter".

I have added `display:none` CSS property to the button, but this will stop form from being submitted. What else could be done ?

Comment: just css display:none;
but then i can't log in using this form because the button is missing :)

Comment: Hiding the button with CSS won't stop the form from submitting when enter is pressed, if you're looking for a quick-fix that's it. Bear in mind you're not doing much for UX here, people expect a call-to-action to continue.

Comment: But so it does. I can't submit if the button is display:none; on css (I got ajax login module active)

Comment: `visibility:hidden` Will work ! Just tried it.

Comment: @2-Stroker With the ajax login module active it probably won't (the JS will intercept the default form submit). Try doing it with jQuery: `$('#login-textfield').keydown(function(e) { if (e.which == 13) { $('#login-button').click(); });` or something

Comment: visibility:hidden works but i dont like much this css solution 'cause the button it's still there taking place.

I'll try to do it with a custom jQuery thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jquery approach to achieve this one which worked for me (drupal 7) is the following code

```
$("#edit-pass").keypress(function(event) {
  if ( event.which == 13 ) {
    $('#edit-submit').click();
   }

});

$("#edit-name").keypress(function(event) {
  if ( event.which == 13 ) {
    $('#edit-submit').click();
}});
```

`#edit-name` and `#edit-pass` are my two login fields.